# React Component with subcomponents or render HTML in parent?

Tags: reactjs

I have a question regarding React patterns. When rendering a component, is it appropriate for this component to render several sub-components, or is it ok to render some HTML in the parent component. Example:

If I have a box that has a heading and a body with list of elements, should I do:

```
var Box = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    <div className="box">
      <HeadingBox />
      <BodyBox />
    </div>
  }
});
```

Or is it ok to do this:

```
var Box = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    <div className="box">
      <div className="heading">
        <div> Heading1 </div>
        <div> Heading2 </div>
      </div>
      <BodyBox />
    </div>
  }
});
```

Any rules to follow here?

Comment: Nope, there are no rules. It's flexible so that you can make the choice that fits your needs best. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It all depends on a context.

The general practice is that if you want to reuse the markup anywhere — you should go with the separate component, so you don't have to repeat yourself. Also if you find yourself writing a large portion of HTML (over 50 lines, for example), separating it into subcomponents will also help.

In other cases, just going with plain HTML will do.

You can find a good description on how best to organize your React code [here](http://blog.siftscience.com/blog/2015/best-practices-for-building-large-react-applications).  (section Separating UI details from interaction logic)

React is no different then other programming framework — it goes best with DRY (Don't repeat yourself).